# Pre-loader won't register on refresh

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using Python and Django to modify a website, I'm using bootstrap 4 as well.
I am attempting to change the pre-loaded spinner currently in use (the typical circle spinner).

I have entered the preloader within my html file, my css file, and made a custom.js file to support the loader yet when I refresh the page the loader shows the standard circle. (I have deleted the previous spinner files and style code but for some reason it still shows when I use "div id=preloader"

Here is my preloader css style.

```
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  /* change if the mask should be a color other than white */
  z-index: 1000;
  /* makes sure it stays on top */
}

.pre-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.double-bounce1,
.double-bounce2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #53dd6c;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.double-bounce2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {

  0%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0)
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0)
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {

  0%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

Here is the custom js file

```
$(window).load(function () {

    // preloader
    $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
    $('#preloader').delay(550).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    $('body').delay(550).css({
        'overflow': 'visible'
    });

});
```

here is my preloader tag in my html file

```
 <div id="preloader">
        <div class="pre-container">
            <div class="spinner">
                <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
                <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There are no error message but I want the bounce to show.

Comment: really stupid question, have you tried clearing the browser cache/trying on a different browser? I think that might be the problem since you said you deleted the old loader but it is showing still when you refresh.

Comment: I actually haven’t, I’ll give It a go and see.  **edit**: that actually took care of It, I Had closed the browser and re-collected static but It wasn’t working. Im not sure what I was going wrong. But I appreciate the help!!!!